# Make number a factor of another number (performance concerns)

Tags: javascript, math

I have this working JavaScript function and I'm wondering if there could be a better way of achieving the same result.

```
function factorise(number, factor){
    if(factor === 0) return 0;
    return Math.round(number / factor) * factor;
}
```

Now If I would want my randomly generated number that happend to be 100 to be divideable by 3 I could use this function.

`factorise(100, 3); ---> 99`

Here are some other examples:

`factorise(27, 5); ---> 25`

`factorise(2095, 27); ---> 1206`

As you can see the returned values contain the factor of the factor number passed to the function. But my concern is the performance of this. Would it be ideal to have it run in physics of a JavaScript game engine? On top of that I'd really want to have a better name for the function.

Comment: why do you need the check for zero and return something outside of a numerical value?

Comment: dividing by 0 is not safe, I don't know if javascript has some safety measure to prevent it but let's be on the safe side. I should however return an int, thanks for poiting it out.

Comment: @JohanSundman In JS, divisions by 0 return NaN, which is falsy. JS doesn't have ints, it only has 64-bit floats.

Comment: @Oriol I see, would it be better to make it return NaN or make it return 0 instead?

Comment: you could set the factor to 1, if zero.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yea but it would just do a normal rounding of the number then.. Idk if that or just returning the same number directly is the best. returning 0 could also be an option.

Comment: @JohanSundman, it's up to you, what fits better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably that code is not your bottleneck. But here is an alternative which does not use floating-point division. It's 10 times faster on Firefox.

```js
function factorise(number, factor) {
  if(factor === 0) return 0;
  var rem = number % factor;
  number -= rem;
  return 2*rem >= factor ? number+factor : number;
}
console.log(factorise(100, 3));   // 99
console.log(factorise(27, 5));    // 25
console.log(factorise(2095, 27)); // 2106
```

It assumes the numbers are non-negative, otherwise you would need some `Math.abs`.

Consider removing the case `factor === 0` and just let it return `NaN`.

Comment: That's a really nice snippet! Did you learn about this in school or somewhere else?

Comment: @JohanSundman Yes, probably in school, or else in university.

Answer (score 1):

You could curry the function with the factor in advance and skip the comparison with zero.

```js
function factorise(factor) {
    return function (number) {
        return Math.round(number / factor) * factor;
    }
}

var factor3 = factorise(3);

console.log(factor3(10));
```